# How to recreate axis = 2 in np.repeat() for Numba (repeat array in the last dimension)

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, numba

I'm trying to convert my code to Numba friendly implementation, however I keep running into errors with the axis argument (as it is not supported). Specifically, I need to use the np.repeat() function in axis=2, or more generally how to repeat the array along the last dimension.

In numpy my code is:

```
original = np.random.rand(1000,1)
no_repeats = 10
big_original = np.repeat(np.expand_dims((5)*original, axis=2), no_repeats, axis=2)
```

How could I rewrite this in a Numba friendly way?

I have tried to use np.dstack:

```
expanded_original = np.expand_dims((5)*original, axis=2)
big_original = np.dstack([expanded_original]*no_repeats)
```

But of course lists aren't a supported datatype. How could I go about this in the most efficient way?

Comment: probably easiest to write: transpose, repeat without axis argument, re-transpose.

Comment: @dankal444 Rewriting as ```big_original = np.transpose(np.repeat(np.transpose(np.expand_dims((5)*original, axis=2)), no_repeats))``` returns a shape of (10000,) instead of the desired (1000, 1, 10)

Comment: The `(5)*original` is unrelated to this question, right?

Comment: @FelixZimmermann Yes, sorry that's not really necessary here but was part of the implementation I needed.

Comment: @codephantom Note you can provide `axes` to transpose function. Not sure why this ends up flattened, but maybe simple `.reshape()` will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what are you exactly trying to do but I guess you want to reproduce the `big_original` array inside a `@njit` numba compiled function. Right?

I so:

```
@njit
def repeat_original(original, no_repeats):
    big_original = np.zeros((*original.shape, no_repeats))
    for i in range(big_original.shape[-1]):
        big_original[...,i] = (5)*original
    return big_original
repeat_original(original, no_repeats)
```

If this is not the answer you were expecting, please try to better specify your problem (e.g. what `expandedGradientMatrix` is) and your expected output.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. I've fixed the mistyping in the post. I am trying to recreate 'big_original' in a Numba-friendly way--essentially the (1000, 1, 10) sized array, which is used in further computations. This line of code sits within a larger function that works within a @njit compiled function, where this one line is causing an error. I don't need to reuse the code necessarily for this one line.

Comment: No problem, try to use the code inside the `repeat_original` then!
If you need it within a larger function you can generate `big_original` how I did in my function (without returning it of course). Hope it helps.

Comment: this is ~2.5x slower than ops code which could just be called in [objmode](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/withobjmode.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the input is always 2D, or by axis=2 you mean "after the last dimension", this will work:

```
import numpy as np
import numba


original = np.random.rand(1000,1)
no_repeats = 10
big_original = np.repeat(np.expand_dims(original, axis=2), no_repeats, axis=2)


@numba.njit()
def repeatnumba(original,no_repeats):
  repeat=original.repeat(no_repeats).reshape(*original.shape,no_repeats )
  return repeat

big_numba = repeatnumba(original,no_repeats)

print(np.allclose(big_original, big_numba))
```

It reproduces the same result as your numpy code. Please note that this depends on the last dimension of the expected result being dimension 2. If your true number of dimensions is different, you might want to use `np.transpose` with a list of dimensions, for example:

```
repeat=np.transpose(repeat,(0,1,-1,2))
```

if your input is 3d and you still want to repeat along dim 2.

If you meant "along the last dimension", please consider updating your title and problem description such that the question might be of more general use.

Comment: I did mean the last dimension, will update now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: great, then this simple solution should work!